# Why does php function import fail?

Tags: php, laravel

I define a function as follows in PHP:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\userOwnedClass;

//If user is member of group with which class has been shared, they can view class.
function canViewClass(User $user, userOwnedClass $class) {
    $priveleged = false;
    foreach($class->shares as $classShare)
    {
        $groupMembers = $classShare->group->members;
        foreach($groupMembers as $groupMember)
        {
            $isMember = ($groupMember->user == $user);
            $priveleged = $priveleged || $isMember;
        }
    }

    return $priveleged;
}
```

I then attempt to invoke it in another file in the namespace `App\Policies`. This fails. I attempted to add an import statement `use App\Policies\canViewClass;`, but I still get a `call to undefined function error`. Can anyone identify my mistake?

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/function_autoloading

Comment: `import` is not a keyword in `php`. Use instead `include`/`include_once` or `require`\`require_once`

Comment: @prograshid OP didn't use `import` as a keyword anywhere in their question

Comment: When I attempt `include canViewClass` or `require canViewClass`, I receive the error `Use of undefined constant canViewClass - assumed 'canViewClass' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)`.

Comment: Try include 'canViewClass.php';

Comment: i think you need to wrap your function inside a class and use `use App\Policies\canViewClass;`

Answer (score 0):

You can manually include your file when needed or use Composer autoloader. For the latter, add this to `autoload` section of `composer.json` and run `composer dump-autoload`:

```
"files": ["app/Policies/somefile.php"]
```

Then you have 3 ways to use it. With import statement:

```
use App\Policies;

$result = Policies\canViewClass();
```

With function import:

```
use function App\Policies\canViewClass;

$result = canViewClass();
```

Using fully qualified name:

```
$result = App\Policies\canViewClass();
```